# SQL Server 2014 : help creating tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I am new to MSSQL 2014 Server, my professor listed these steps to make a table, I don't know the proper steps to create tables in the pictures listed below, please help.

> 1. Create and populate (insert values) the following tables per table description and data values provided
>
>    - DEPARTMENT
>    - EMPLOYEE
>    - PROJECT
>    - ASSIGNMENT
> 2. Add a SQL Comment to include /* *** Your First Name_Your Last Name*** */ when inserting corresponding values for each table.
>
> [image: table 1]
>
> [image: table 2]

What I tried so far:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT( 
    DepartmentName Text(35) PRIMARY KEY, 
    BudgetCode Text(30) NOT NULL, 
    OfficeNumber Text(15) NOT NULL, 
    Phone Text(12) NOT NULL, );
```

I have put this to my query and the error is

> Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot specify a column width on data type text.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]

Comment: CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
DepartmentName Text(35) PRIMARY KEY,
BudgetCode Text(30) NOT NULL,
OfficeNumber Text(15) NOT NULL,
Phone Text(12) NOT NULL,
);

I have put this to my query and there are errors telling me                 Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot specify a column width on data type text.

Comment: TEXT in SQL-server isn't a datatype you add a length to. VARCHAR(), CHAR(), NVARCHAR(), NCHAR() are types of strings that you can assign a length to.  So if you want to support latin/unicome characters use the nchar and nvarchar otherwise use varchar and char.  VARHCAR() is the most prevalent for US formats

Comment: CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
DepartmentName Char(35) PRIMARY KEY,
BudgetCode Char(30) NOT NULL,
OfficeNumber Char(15) NOT NULL,
Phone Char(12) NOT NULL,
);

Comment: Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'DEPARTMENT' in the database.
When I did that there was another message saying Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'DEPARTMENT' in the database.

Comment: That means an object by the name of department already exists you can delete it. "DROP TABLE DEPARTMENT" or you can look at its definition and see what is there. If you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) expand the database, tables, and then columns to figure it out or right click on the table name and choose design and it will show you the code/strucutre

Answer (score 0):

Try this(I assume that your table exists in `dbo` schema):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.DEPARTMENT', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE DEPARTMENT
END
GO
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT( 
    DepartmentName varchar(35) PRIMARY KEY, 
    BudgetCode varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    OfficeNumber varchar(15) NOT NULL, 
    Phone varchar(12) NOT NULL
);
```

You can not define width for `Text` data type. In case which you need to define width you can use `char` or `varchar` data types. Also keep in mind that if you need to work with Unicode characters then you will need to use `nchar` or `nvarchar` instead.